# Jenkins pipeline from scp throws stderr: fatal: not in a git directory

Tags: docker, jenkins, debian, centos7

We upgrade to "Jenkins 2.387.2" recently and started seeing below error for all the jenkins pipeline where we were using Jenkinsfile from git scm.

```
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git config remote.origin.url git@github.com:jenkinsci/pipeline-examples.git" returned status code 128:
15:33:37  stdout: 
15:33:37  stderr: fatal: not in a git directory
15:33:37  
15:33:37    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2732)
15:33:37    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2658)
15:33:37    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2654)
15:33:37    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommand(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1979)
15:33:37    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommand(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1991)
15:33:37    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.setRemoteUrl(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1599)
15:33:37    at hudson.plugins.git.GitAPI.setRemoteUrl(GitAPI.java:161)
15:33:37    at jenkins.plugins.git.GitSCMFileSystem$BuilderImpl.build(GitSCMFileSystem.java:393)
15:33:37    at jenkins.scm.api.SCMFileSystem.of(SCMFileSystem.java:219)
15:33:37    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScmFlowDefinition.create(CpsScmFlowDefinition.java:118)
15:33:37    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScmFlowDefinition.create(CpsScmFlowDefinition.java:70)
15:33:37    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun.run(WorkflowRun.java:312)
15:33:37    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:101)
```

when I use pipeline code directly in the job, It works fine and all git operations works fine in the pipeline as well.

Git client plugin (git-client): 4.2.0
Git plugin (git): 5.0.2

Jenkins is running in kubernetes and the agent is running in pod. Even for fresh pipeline, I am able to reproduce this. This is only happening when I use pipeline code from SCM.

Any idea what's wrong here?

***Update 1 :***

What I tested is, I created a fresh instance of Jenkins from the same version (2.387.2) and ran the same job and it works fine. So look like there is some issue with my jenkins only.

***Update 2 (Workaround)***:

I found the issue similar to what mentioned [here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/helm-charts/issues/728) . So I tried to switch to a centos based image `jenkins/jenkins:lts-centos7-jdk11` and it worked. I was using `jenkins/jenkins:lts-jdk11` before which is debian based image. I am still not sure why centos and debian images behave differently with EFS filesystem.

Comment: `stderr: fatal: not in a git directory` that sounds like a local issue. What about deleting the workspace and try it again?

Comment: It runs in a container agent and even for fresh pipeline, I am able to reproduce this. This is only happening when I use SCP plugin to checkout code in freestyle job.

Comment: So you narrowed down enough. You have 2 options from here: a) you don't use the plugin b) you open a bug-report for them

Comment: Ok, So what i tested is, I created a fresh instance of Jenkins from the same version (2.387.2) and ran the same job and it works fine. So look like there is some issue with my jenkins only.

Comment: Some 3rdparty version still may differ... Like git or the git plugin or something else what is involved here...

Comment: So I narrowed down further and I can see jenkins_home permissions are set to different user and group. I am using EFS volume as jenkins home folder. Since the SCM trying to download jenkinsfile to a local workspace, it's not able to do that. There is no option to set node before Jenkinsfile is loaded in pipeline job, I need to see what options are left for me. One is move to ebs volume mounts.

Comment: I ran into the same issue and switching to jenkins/jenkins:lts-centos7-jdk11 image worked for me as well. I'm planning on replacing jenkins so that is a great workaround until I replace it.  if you post update 2 as an answer, I'll vote it up.

Answer (score 3):

The reason centos7 image is working is because it's using an old version of git.

```
$ docker run -it jenkins/jenkins:lts-jdk11 git --version
git version 2.30.2

$ docker run -it jenkins/jenkins:lts-centos7-jdk11 git --version
git version 1.8.3.1
```

Command line git included in recent container images includes a fix for a [security issue](https://security-tracker.debian.org/tracker/CVE-2022-24765). Command line git now refuses to perform operations in repositories when the directory is not owned by the current user.

> Command line git has decided that it is dangerous to perform git operations in a directory owned by a different user. I may consider a way to better detect it and better alert the administrator that there is a problem, but ultimately it is a mistake to perform git operations in a directory owned by a different user without intentionally configuring the safe.directory to allow it.

centos7 is going to be retired on November 2023 and Jenkins shows a warning to upgrade to different OS.

**If you wish to circumvent the newly introduced security checks** (I should point out that they're probably implemented for good reason and it's generally not recommended to disable them ), you have the option to execute the following command:

```
git config --global --add safe.directory "*"
```

You can run this command within any git repository on the Jenkins master.

Alternatively, you can achieve the same effect by creating a `~/.gitconfig` file with the following content:

```
[safe]
    directory = *
```

I found that this solution resolved the issues I was encountering with Jenkins, which had been deployed via this helm chart and was running on AWS EKS with EFS mounting.

Comment: HI @Elsamni,

what is the meaning of safe directory with *, right now i can above changes under .gitconfig, due to this jenkins scm checkout failed 

pipeline.git" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: fatal: not in a git directory

Answer (score 1):

TLDR: This is just a workaround. Change you base image to centos7

I found that this is happening since i moved to EFS based storage class for my jenkins home mount. The issue was not observed with gp2 and ebs volume mounts. The issue is disussed in some detail [here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/helm-charts/issues/728). I can't update the csi driver so i tried changing the base image. When I use a centos7 based image, Git checkout works properly.

Answer (score 0):

I'd post this as a comment to the question but my account is too new.

Check the file ownership in the persistent volume. I don't know if my situation is similar to yours. I'm running a Kubernetes cluster with a single worker agent and using local storage for my persistent volume.

I ran into the same error on a jenkins:lts pod on Kubernetes. I had previously copied the mounted volume files in the Kubernetes node, recreated the persistent volume and pod, and "restored" back my earlier copy. In the process, it seems that the permissions were changed so that root was the owner of the files in the volume (I used sudo when making the copy). I changed the ownership back to the Kubernetes user and I was able to run my job successfully again.

Comment: You can change permissions as this was a local storage. I am using EFS and permissions are set differently. But based on what you trying, I can certainly create an init script that will change the groupid and useid of  jenkins user in pod to match that of volume mount